# How To Find Number Of Extentions

Tags: screeps

I have tried `Game.STRUCTURE_EXTENSION.length` and `Game.STRUCTURES.E.length`, but these either cause an error, or are undefined - even though I have extensions.

Is there a global variable for extensions, or is there some way to find the number of extensions through a loop. Because i need my spawn to know how many extensions there are to determine what to spawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STRUCTURE_EXTENSION` is just a number constant, not an array.

In order to calculate the total number of extensions in a room where your spawn is located you can do the following:

```
var extensions = Game.spawns.Spawn1.room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, {
  filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION }
});
console.log(extensions.length);
```

See [`Room.find`](https://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#find) method in documentaion.

Comment: This didn't work for me (yielded 0).  But I changed the references to just their names without the "Game." and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Roll through your rooms, or you could just count one room.

```
var extensionCount = 0;
for(var roomName in Game.rooms) {
    extensionCount += Game.rooms[roomName].find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES,{
        filter: function(object){return object.structureType === STRUCTURE_EXTENSION;
    }).length;
}
```

using **[room.find](https://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#find)** method